# Gradient theorem

Tags: real-analysis

My question is more about terminology in the gradient theorem formula.

I recall what is written in a book:

Gradient theorem: If $f$ is a continuously differentiable scalar field, then
\begin{gather*}
\int\int\int_V \ \boldsymbol{grad}\ f \ dV = \int\int_S \ f \ d\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\sigma}.
\end{gather*}

So it seems to me that the left-hand side gives a vector and the right-hand side a scalar. Maybe, is it an abuse of notation ?

Because before this theorem, obviously, I have this lemma:

If $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable scalar field and if $\stackrel{\rightarrow}{d}$ is a unit vector, then
\begin{gather*}
\int\int\int_V \ \boldsymbol{grad}\ f \ \cdot \stackrel{\rightarrow}{d} dV = \int\int_S \ f \ \stackrel{\rightarrow}{d} \cdot \stackrel{\rightarrow}{n} d\sigma.
\end{gather*}

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both vectors in the first equations.

$$\iiint_V \vec{\nabla}f dV = \iint f d\vec{\sigma}$$

The gradient of a scalar field $\vec{\nabla}{f}$ is a vector, as is $d\vec{\sigma}.$

Similarly, they're both scalars in the second equation.

Comment: Oooh yes I see.. So tell me if I am wrong:

The gradient theorem says:  

$\iiint_V \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dV = \iint_S fn_x d\sigma$, also when replacing $x$ by $y$ or $z$, i.e. the gradient theorem is the particular case of the lemma when $\vec{d}$ equals one vector of the basis $(\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k})$, right ?

Thank you.

Marcus

Comment: I don't think the right side of the equation is quite correct. Check [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceIntegral.html) for more detail on $d\vec{\sigma}$. The linked page refers to it as $d\vec{a}.$

Comment: Actually, I may have spoken prematurely.  Whether the RHS is correct or not depends on how you express $d\sigma$!  But check there just in case.